maxFileSize is not behaving as expected in SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy in logback-1.5.6
I am trying to test the SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy in Logback. The time-based rolling is working fine, but I'm having trouble with the size-based rolling. I expect the file to roll over when it reaches the maximum file size of 8 KB, but this isn't happening.
Here is the logback configuration.
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} -%kvp- %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>8KB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name = "org.security" level = "info" additivity= "false">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>

And here is the Test file to generate logs.
public class TimeAndSizeBasedRollingPolicyExample {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeAndSizeBasedRollingPolicyExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int j = 0;
        while(j < 5) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20480; i++) {
                logger.info("generating code ");
            }
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            j++;
        }
    }
}

And here is the outcome:

Thank you.
